# Get stuck on having the right python to install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, terminal

I try to install TensorFlow by following the steps in [Professor Jeff Heaton's video](https://youtu.be/_CO-ND1FTOU), and I get stuck in the step of making sure I have the correct python after installing miniforge.

According to Jeff, the command should respond with something similar to:`/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/python` when typing in `which python` in the terminal

However, mine is `/Users/kamingleung/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`. I tried to change directory by doing `cd opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base`. The terminal shows that `zsh: no such file or directory: cd: no such file or directory: opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base`

Can anyone please tell me how I can fix this problem and have the correct python to install tensorflow?

I am using Python 3.8.9 and MacBook Air (Version 11.6, M1 chip, Z-shell)

Comment: Instead of running `cd/opt/homebrew/Caskroom` run `cd /opt/homebrew/Caskroom` with a space after `cd`

Comment: Ok I fixed this typo, but now I could not get to the base in miniforge. Could you please look at the post again? I just updated it. Thank you, Andrew

Comment: miniforge is a different package from anaconda. If you install all of the dependencies the same way (using the same conda / pip install commands), I assume it shouldn't matter that you're using that python version

Comment: If you still need to use miniforge, I assume you can install it by running [`brew install --cask miniforge`](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/miniforge)

Comment: Please have a look at the instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) to install correct [python](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#macos) and tensorflow in your system.